# Discord.JS Send message to tagged user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command that reads an element from `args` and then sends it to the tagged user but I'm getting an error.

My Code:

````js
if (cmd === '!message'){
   if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
      message.channel.send("```Send Message to: ?```")
   } else {
      const username = args[1];
      const fetchuser = guild.members.fetch(username.id)
      var message = args[2];
      fetchuser.message.send(`${message.author} send you a message: ${message}`)
   }
}
````

Error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:373:29)
at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
```

Comment: What is `args`? An array? What is `args[1]`? A string? If `args[1]` is not an object, you can't use `username.id`. And the error seems to be unrelated to the code you posted.

Comment: Adding on. There will never be an `id` property which extends off a username property.

Comment: I mean for example to do !message @username Hello and i want the bot to send dm to the tagged user with the message "Hello"

Comment: You should post details of your args array to make answering the question easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions.members.first()` to get the tagged member. You don't need to fetch the guild member if you use `mentions.members` instead of `mentions.users`:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'message') {
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!mentionedMember) {
      return message.reply('You need to mention someone!');
    }

    const text = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    mentionedMember.send(text);
  }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have `args` defined, but here is a quick example of DMing a specified user with args:

```
let dmUser = message.mentions.users.first();
let dmArgs = args.join(" ").slice(8);
dmUser.send(dmArgs);
```

Please feel free to change this how you like. Basically what this does is it sets a new `let` variable equal to fetch a mentioned user from the server the message was sent from. The `dmArgs` variable is just a more organized way to store args, I used .slice to slice off the command and the prefix from the desired argument. Finally, you send it.